# Сохранение doc документа из HTML

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, в котором я вывожу HTML страницу. В начале кода вставил

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=Report.doc");
```

и сразу идет скачивание этой страницы в .doc документ.

А как сохранить этот документ на сервере?

Comment: Попробуйте получить эту страницу с другой курлом(пример отличного костыля) например=))) Ну или `file_get_contents()`

Comment: 1) Может убрать attachment? 2) Как отображается страница. Старая форма вывода "встроеного" не-html-ного содержимого - `<embed src=>` по-новому неподскажу. Думаю embed поможет. Не скачивают браузеры - разве что pdf, и то не все.

Comment: @nick_n_a а как получить pdf ? из html страницы? так было бы даже лучше

Comment: Стоп, "сохраниение doc файла" и "конвертация html в doc" - это соовсем разные вещи. Если вам нужна конвертация html в pdf (или в doc) то задайте вопрос по-другому - вопрос тогда - уточнить **отредактировать**. Если вы хотите с одной страницы, отобразить pdf который есть на сервере без скачивание то вам embed `<html><body><embed width=600 height=300 src=mypdf.pdf >`